Restore default behavior change in clang-format 18 for space after function before bracket
In clang-format 17 with an empty config file, clang-format would remove any space after a function before the bracket on a single line.
`
#ifndef LIBRARY_CSVLOG_HPP
#define LIBRARY_CSVLOG_HPP

class CsvLog {
  void Print(const char *value){};
};

#endif

After updating to clang-format 18 with the same empty config file a space is inserted between ) and { as shown.
#ifndef LIBRARY_CSVLOG_HPP
#define LIBRARY_CSVLOG_HPP

class CsvLog {
  void Print(const char *value) {};
};

#endif

Is there something can be inserted into the .clang-format file to restore the old default behavior?  This can be reproduced using the https://clang-format-configurator.site
